# How to launch external app (NDrive) from iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, coordinates

I want to launch ndrive from an iphone app with coordinates. 
I tried this, but don´t know the parameters for the coordinates.

```
NSString *stringURL = @"ndrive//";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Anyone know what URL Scheme to use? I searched the web but couldn´t find an answer.

Comment: iOS custom protocols are `app:` so it's probably `ndrive:`. As for the parameters - I don't know, you'd have to contact ndrive. But, they may just follow Google and use `ndrive:?sll=37.0625,-95.677068`

Comment: The app i want to call is tmn-drive, it´s built on top of ndrive, that´s why i said i wanted to launch ndrive. I used "tmn-drive:" but it didn´t oppend. Does every app has a url-sheme or the developer has to deliberated register it? Cause there may be the case of the developer hasn´t any url scheme registered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1818215/74118) might help you:

> If you have access to the application bundles (in other words, you own
>   the applications so the iTunes bundles are in ~/Music/iTunes/Mobile
>   Applications), you can unzip these .ipa bundles and take a look at
>   their Info.plist files.
>
> You should look to see if there are any URL schemes defined by looking
>   for any values in an array at
>   ["CFBundleURLTypes"]["CFBundleURLSchemes"]. You can take a gander at
>   http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html
>   for a more in-depth explanation.

A comment on that question suggests that NDrive has no custom URL scheme.

Comment: This was usefull. This way i couldn´t see the plist and verify that there is no url scheme. Can´t do nothing beyond this point.

Comment: At least you'll save some time thinking about it.